# Google Drive Api and Google Drive Web

Tags: google-drive-api

I am developing an app which use google drive javascript api. I have called some simple function, for example, to "create folder" in order to create a folder in drive. In my app, it instantly updated and refreshed such that I get the folder I create in the drive using the api. However, when I go to docs.google.com, I did not see my folder there.

How can this happen? Is there something wrong? Or it takes time for the docs.google.com to refresh? Because what I want is that after user use my app to update the drive, they can see it immediately in the docs.google.com

Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

Each folder has a list of parents. If you create a folder with no parents, it will exist in Drive, but you will not see it on the Drive front-end unless you search for it.

In Drive, 'My Drive' is the root folder, which can be found using [About/Get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about/get). If you set your folder to have this as a parent on creation (or update it after), you will be able to see it in the front end.